# Get HTML textbox value with Flash

Tags: javascript, html, flash, variables, input

I have a textbox on a page in which the value of it changes on the users requirements. For convenience, I have added a flash button next to it to copy the value of the box.
As the page doesn't reload, is there a way that clicking the flash button would pull in the textbox data ready to write to the clipboard? I have previously been using a variable at the end of the file name but this requires a reload (eg `name.swf?something=helloWorld`), I want to avoid this.

Can be `AS2`, `AS3`, `JS`, `jQuery` or anything that would get this working?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this jquery plugin:
http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/clipboard

> "Clipboard is a simple jQuery plugin that allows you to copy text in
>   cross-browser fashion, using Internet Explorer's native method, and a
>   Flash helper in other browsers. Compatible with jQuery 1.2.x and
>   1.3.x, requires Flash 8+ in non-IE browsers."

Comment: I found it a bit tricky to use with my site design but it does what it says on the tin. I also found (http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/)